# How do I bind to UDP port 53 in GCE (Container-Optimized OS)?

Tags: docker, linux-networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, tcpip

**Is there any way to free up UDP port 53 on my GCE instance so that I can bind to it?**

I'm running a container on GCE that needs to listen on UDP port 53, as it's listening for DNS connections. However, when I try to run my container and bind to UDP port 53, I get the following error message:

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external
>   connectivity on endpoint 
>   ():
>   Error starting userland proxy: listen udp 0.0.0.0:53: bind: address
>   already in use.

Checking for open ports shows that `127.0.0.53` is connected on UDP port 53:

```sh
$ netstat -tuln | grep 53
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*
```

Reading through the documentation, the only reference to something like this was zonal DNS, which can be disabled by setting the instance or project metadata `VmDnsSetting=GlobalOnly` ([article here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#disabling-zonal-dns)). I did this, and the port binding is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

**It appears that the culprit is the `systemd-resolved` service.**

You can stop the service with the command `$ sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved`.

---

### More details

In order to do this on GCE using Google's container-optimized OS ("COS"), I needed to deselect the option to boot from a container image, and then manually go in and enter the relevant commands to get the environment up and running as follows.

The following 2 commands are needed to pull from a private GCR registry:

`$ docker-credential-gcr configure-docker`

`$ docker pull gcr.io/<project>/<container>`

Stop the `systemd-resolved` service:

`$ sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved`

Start the docker container (note the `--network host` flag, which is what COS does by default when you select the option to boot from a container image in the instance configuration):

`$ docker run -d --network host --restart=unless-stopped <container>`

Open the relevant ports (needed when not explicitly booting from a container image when configuring the instance):

`$ sudo iptables -w -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`

`$ sudo iptables -w -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT`

### A note on automation

Note that you can't put the first command (`$ docker-credential-gcr configure-docker`) in the startup script, as it fails due to the `/root/.docker/` directory being read-only; startup scripts are run as root once networking is available.

I still haven't figured this one out yet, but I will update this answer once I have, to make it a little less manual for anyone else reading this.

#### Update on automation

It turns out that you can create a user in a `cloud-init` script, then use `$ su - <user>` in your startup script before running the `$ docker-credential-gcr configure-docker` command as that user to save the credentials (referenced in [this support forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/gce-discussion/lPICyqIG9IQ)). However, this is way too hacky for me, so I've opted to just run the commands manually once the GCE instance is spun up to get Docker running properly.

#### tl;dr: How to unbind port 53 on startup

However, for anyone who may be looking to just unbind port 53 on startup, you can do so with the following startup script:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

systemctl stop systemd-resolved
```

Instructions for adding a startup script to your VM on GCE can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).